# Need to code a script to end a process in windows 7

Tags: windows, process

I need to make a script or program that detects when a certain program is open and closed. When the program is closed, the script/program should end another process that is running. How should I go about doing this and how do I code this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? How did it go?

Comment: I have no idea how to even start. I don't know if I should use a windows script or something else? Didn't see much on his after googling around,

Answer (score 0):

This snip verifies if calc.exe is running, if not, it kills all notepad.exe instances.  Run from Powershell.

```
    $path = "C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe"
    get-process | where-object {$_.Path -eq $path } | measure-object | where-object { $_.Count -eq 0} | foreach-object {taskkill /f /IM  notepad.exe}
#
```